# WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient shows an annoy message box of "You have successfully signed in"

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure-mobile-service to login facebook. However, it shows the message after logging in. How to hide the message box?

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mysite.azurewebsites.net');
client.login('facebook', $scope.token).done(function (result) {
    ......
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible to do. The `.auth/login/done` is a built-in page which we don't have much control on.

Comment: Do you know any third party library for azure backbend?

Comment: Curiously, `.auth/login/done` is not part of the javascript library provided by Microsoft? A friend of mine uses a different library to for Facebook login and he doesn't have the issue (He doesn't use Azure).

Comment: I am getting the same message and I am using the Google auth provider in Azure mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

Well, to avoid this message you can use this [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) to contact the Facebook and then provide the returned access token to your App Service for authentication.

Here is sample code you can use in your mobile clientend:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], function(data) {

    client.login('facebook', {"access_token": data.authResponse.accessToken}).done(function (result) {
        console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
    });

}, function (error) {
    console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```